# AngularJS - ngRoute not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I have a quick question regarding Angular ngRoute. I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYUQmm-xfIY) but cant the problem within my code. It seems that the ngRoute function is not working properly. I am using c9 as my IDE.

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute',
'ui.bootstrap']).
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('partials/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'homeController'});
    $routeProvider.when('partials/about', {templateUrl: 'partials/about.html', controller: 'aboutController'});
    $routeProvider.when('partials/contact', {templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html', controller: 'contactController'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});
}]);
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var port = process.env.PORT;
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'views'));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')));

app.get('*', function(req,res){
  res.render('index.ejs');
});


app.get('/home', function(req,res){
    res.render('index');
});


app.listen(port,function(){
  console.log('Server Running .... PORT: ' + port);
})
```

**index.ejs**

```
  ---> Bootstrap static nav bar code...
  <div class="container">

    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: Is there any error on the console?

Comment: No error in console

Comment: Where is your div with `id=myApp` in your ejs code?

Comment: "Not working properly" what do you mean ?

Comment: What is the route you tried. Your routes are defined like `localhost:9000/#/partials/home` since you didn't enable the HTML5 mode.

Comment: This is how I used the ng-app directive in my index.ejs file: <html lang="en" ng-app = "myApp"> . // Not working -> its not loading the partials in my ngview directive